# how to calculate sum database table where number of column in table?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
 $sql="SELECT SUM(`2014jan1`,`2014jan2`,`2014jan3`,`2014jan4`,`2014jan5`,`2014jan6`,`2014jan7`,`2014jan8`,`2014jan9`,`2014jan10`,`2014jan11`,`2014jan12`,`2014jan13`,`2014jan14`,`2014jan15`,`2014jan16`,`2014jan17`,`2014jan18`,`2014jan19`,`2014jan20`,`2014jan21`,`2014jan222`,`2014jan23`,`2014jan24`,`2014jan25`,`2014jan26`,`2014jan27`,`2014jan28`,`2014jan29`,`2014jan30`,`2014jan31`) as `total` FROM `jan` WHERE class like '$class%' and roll like'$roll')";
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

this is a correct syntax ? or check my code? thank you ?

Comment: No, it's not correct syntax (the `SUM()` function takes only one argument: an expression to be aggregated by summation for each group).  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Does your table comprise all those columns?  If so, you really should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You have table field for each day in month? You should first restructure your table.
Ie, create table with fields: class, roll, year, month, day, attendance.
So, instead storing ZZ data for the XX class and YY roll in lets say 2014jan4 field, you would store your data something like this:

```
Field:  class   roll    year    month    day    attendance 
Value:     XX     YY    2014      jan      3            ZZ
```

Then you can query it like:

`$sql="SELECT SUM(attendance) as total FROM YourTable WHERE class like '$class%' and roll like '$roll' and year like '2014' and month like 'jan')";`

Without knowing what are you trying to accomplish, above is just the idea to get you going in right direction.